# Problemas con Domain storage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar, ts

Estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto con typescript en quasar y node por el lado del backend, y estoy intentando comunicar 2 ambientes entre si utilizando cross-domain-storage/guest, este es mi código para aquello:

import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
import Menu from 'pages/core/menu/Menu.vue';
import createGuest from 'cross-domain-storage/guest';

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Menu,
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({ isLoggedIn: 'User/isLoggedIn_getter' }),
  },
  created(): void {
    try{
      if (
        localStorage.getItem('jwt_pricing_management') === '' ||
        localStorage.getItem('jwt_pricing_management') === undefined ||
        localStorage.getItem('jwt_pricing_management') === null
      ) {
        const bazStorage = createGuest(window.URL_INTRANET_SSO);
        bazStorage.get('jwtToken', (error: Error, value: string | null) => {
          if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            location.replace(window.URL_INTRANET_SSO);
          } else if (
            value !== undefined &&
            value !== '' &&
            value !== null &&
            localStorage.getItem('jwt_pricing_management') !== value
          ) {
            localStorage.setItem('jwt_pricing_management', value);
            bazStorage.close();
            location.reload();
          } else if (value === undefined || value === '' || value === null) {
            location.replace(window.URL_INTRANET_SSO);
          }
        });
      } else {
        this.$router.push('/pricingManagement');
      }
    } catch (err){
      console.error(err)
    }
    }
});
```

Esto está en un archivo typescript, pero al momento de que se ejecuta este código me genera el siguiente error:

dex.js:93 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': Invalid target origin ''https://intranettest.pf100.cl/intranet/';' in a call to 'postMessage'.
at message (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/cross-domain-storage/distribution/guest/index.js:93:27)
at checkConnected (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/cross-domain-storage/distribution/guest/index.js:128:9)
m

No sé como solucoinar esto, si alguien pudiera ayudarme, se  lo agradecería un montón

Comment: Hola user224276, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta, elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, gracias.

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta, muchas gracias por la sugerencia